# What is block type core/text_list in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

What is `core/text_list` below and how does it work? I am checking the `core` folder but can't find explanation about how `text_list` works.

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/core 

<block type="core/text_list" name="before_body_end" as="before_body_end" translate="label">
            <label>Page Bottom</label>
            <block type="page/html_cookieNotice" name="global_cookie_notice" as ="global_cookie_notice" template="page/html/cookienotice.phtml" before="-" />
        </block>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a structural block. Blocks of type `core/text_list` will automatically render all its children without the need to call the `getChildHtml()` method. You can see the relevant class [here](http://www.freegento.com/doc/db/da3/_core_2_block_2_text_2_list_8php-source.html).

The translate attribute contains a space-delimited list of tag names that needs to be translated, `<label>` in your example.

A new block `cookieNotice` is being added before the body end using the template you provided to it `page/html/cookienotice.phtml`